# Number converted in 1e+30

Tags: javascript

How to convert `1e+30` to 1000000000000000000000000000000

I want number as it is entered by User do not convert like `1e+30`.

How can achieve this? Is there any way to display actual digits after parse it to **float** or **int**?

Comment: what about `1e30` ? :)

Comment: You do realize that javascript cannot handle numbers of 30 digits right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It's my requirement to remain in actual digits.

Answer (score 6):

The core library doesn't give you any support for numbers that don't fit into the native `number` type, so you'll probably want to use a third party library to help you with large decimals.

For example, https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/

```
new Decimal('1e+30').toFixed()
// "1000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: I think you mean core **language**. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Meh. I know that's the terminology that JS uses, but it's goofy.

Comment: Please give me example I stuck by this problem.

Comment: @Sadikhasan My answer already contains an example. What more are you asking?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
(1000000000000000000000000000000).toLocaleString("en-US", { useGrouping: false })
```

Comment: @Sadikhasan It works with float numbers (in JS there is no difference between integers and floats). However, with so huge numbers you can't have decimal precision (in fact, `1000000000000000000000000000000 == 1000000000000000010000000000000`).

Comment: This should be the answer!It works perfectly and is very simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `new Array()` and `String.replace`, but it will only be in the form of `String`

```
function toNum(n) {
   var nStr = (n + ""); 
   if(nStr.indexOf(".") > -1) 
      nStr = nStr.replace(".","").replace(/\d+$/, function(m){ return --m; });
   return nStr.replace(/(\d+)e\+?(\d+)/, function(m, g1, g2){
      return g1 + new Array(+g2).join("0") + "0";
   })
}
console.log(toNum(1e+30)); // "1000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Now it's more robust as it doesn't fail even if a really huge number such as `12e100` which will be converted to `1.2e+101`, is provided as the `.` is removed and the last set of digits decremented once. But still 100% accuracy can't be ensured but that is because of limitations of floatation maths in javascript.

Comment: @Sadikhasan It is working. First it is getting converted to `1e+28` and it's working fine.

Comment: `parseFloat((10000000000000000000000000000.55)` is eqaul to `1e+28`

Comment: It display only `10000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Can you show me in jsfiddle example which you say `it's working fine`